# jQuery outerHeight is not returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically set the height of the webpage content by subtracting the header and footer values from the window size and setting the content to this value on document load.

Each of the functions parameters takes in an element id in order to grab the element height; excluding the content parameter.

```
 function setH(header, content, footer) 
{
    winH = top.innerHeight;
    winTitle = 32; // height value of the window title (part of the header)
    headH = $(header).outerHeight(true);
    footH = $(footer).outerHeight(true);
    contentH = winH - winTitle - headH - footH;
    $(content).css({'height' : (contentH) + 'px','overflow-y' : 'scroll'});
}
```

The issue that I am running into is the outerHeight values are returning the wrong values. The header returns 23px and footer 40px.

When examining the elements in FF and Chrome the values are 25px and 44px.

I have tried using innerHeight,, outerHeight and outerHeight(true) but not getting the correct values.

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? or an alternative way to setting the height of the content dynamically? I'm running out of hair to pull so any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am working with content in iframes. The following: `winH = top.innerHeight` is getting the height value of the top most iframe window.

Comment: What is `top`? What does it hold? Please show your layout too.

Comment: I have custom windows that pop up in iframes; top is grabbing the top most iframe height.

Answer (score 17):

One thing to try which helped me is to put the code that checks `outerHeight()` in `$(window).load()` and not `$(document).ready()`. Obviously in many cases it's fine to use `$(document.ready()`, but sometimes the incorrect value of `outerHeight()` is caused from elements not being completely loaded.

Comment: One thing I should add, `(window).load()` is called after ALL elements on the page have finished loading, including images.

Comment: Hello @Gaving,
Could you please help me with how I should have $(window).load() with outerHeight() ? I am new to JS, and not sure how the code would be alike.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified a script I use for calculating screenwidth/height. See if this works:

```
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
        winTitle = 32;
        headH = $(header).outerHeight(true);
        footH = $(footer).outerHeight(true);
        contentH = viewportheight - winTitle - headH - footH;
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        winTitle = 32;
        headH = $(header).outerHeight(true);
        footH = $(footer).outerHeight(true);
        contentH = viewportheight - winTitle - headH - footH;
    }

    // older versions of IE

    else {

    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    }
    document.getElementById("content id").style.height = contentH + "px";
```

Comment: I modified your script to work with my current code but the values it's returning are the same from my original code.

Comment: Are the header and footer dynamic? If not you could replace .outerHeight(true) with the amount of pixels their height is.

Comment: That is my current work around but I need the code to be as dynamic as possible. Therefor I need to be able to get the values.

Comment: I understand, I'll dig into this.

Comment: The issue seems to be Firefox specific. Apparently the header and footer heights are 23px and 40px while in Firefox they are 25px and 44px. This leads me to believe it is an issue with how the browser displays the content.

Comment: If that´s the case you might wanna´ add a Style Reset to ensure browser consistency. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/