# Why outerHeight is not returning the correct value in the chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, height

My script like this :

```
$('table tbody td').eq(0).outerHeight();
```

In the safari, it returning the correct value. But in the chrome is not returning the correct value

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: May be a duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480108/jquery-outerheight-is-not-returning-the-correct-value

Comment: @Sonia I had read it, but I don't find a solution. My case is table. Maybe it's different

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and consider the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/): "*Although .outerHeight() can be used on table elements, it may give unexpected results on tables using the border-collapse: collapse CSS property.*"